# tkinter winfo_children dynamic association

Tags: python-2.7, python-3.x, tkinter

I'm trying to figure out if an `Entry` is blank, but instead it skips over it in my code and appends the next `Entry` object, if the `Entry` has data, to the array. When I try to identify the object it gives a reference, but not the type of object (i.e. `.140594722293880....`).
I've tried `if i.get() != "":` and `None`, is there a way to identify an empty `Entry`?

```
import os,sys
import Tkinter as tkinter
import ttk
class CLASSTHING():
   def __init__(self):
        top = tkinter.Tk()
        top.geometry('1200x150')
        top.title('')
        master = ttk.Frame(top)
        n = ttk.Notebook(master)
        f1 = ttk.Frame(n)
        for x in range(0,len(labelstr) -1):
            tkinter.Label(f1, text=labelstr[x], width=len(labelstr[x])).grid(row=x,column=0)
            tkinter.Entry(f1, width=100).grid(row=x,column=1)
        submit = tkinter.Button(top,text="submit",command= lambda: 
self.enterData([f1])
        submit.place(x=1152,y=25)    
        n.add(f1,text='1')
        top.mainloop()

    def enterData(self,Frame):
        ary = []
        for a in frame:
            for i in a.winfo_children():
                ary.append(i.get())
```

My coding is compatible with both Python 3 and 2. If you have a suggestion, please give whichever you know best.

Comment: _"My coding is compatible with both 3 and 2."_ Right now it's compatible with neither, because `tkinter` isn't a built-in module in 2.7, and `print ary` isn't legal syntax in 3.X ;-) Please provide a [mcve] that runs and demonstrates your problem.

Comment: import Tkinter as tkinter....

Comment: Ok, go ahead and include that in your MCVE whenever it's ready to go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `winfo_class` method to get the class for any Tk or Ttk widget. For Entry widgets the class is "Entry", a ttk entry widget would be "TEntry". This is application specific though as the programmer may assign a different class to a widget to associate a different visual style in ttk or different options in standard Tk.